# move_uploaded_file is making a file called 'array'?

Tags: php, file-upload

the following piece of code recognizes the image through getimagesize() but then when i try to move the file to an uploaded folder it moves the file there but says it's an array?  im confused because im not setting any variables as an array?

```
<?php 

//simple image check using getimagesize() instead of extensions

if($_FILES){
  $empty_check = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
      if(empty($empty_check)){
           echo 'this is not an image';
      }
      else{

           echo 'you have uploaded ' . explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])[0].' 

and it is a ' . explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])[1].'.'; 
           //an example of how i would extract the extension
$target = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target.'\\'.$_FILES['file']);

}

}



?>
```

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` is an array, you're trying to use it as the target filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_FILES['file']
```

is an array, you're trying to use it as the target filename; 
**comment of deceze.**

Echo the file you want to move/save, then you should see what he mentioned..

When using move_uploaded_file you get to pick the filename, so you can pick anything you want.

When you upload the file, its put into a temporary directory with a temporary name, move_uploaded_file() allows you to move that file and in that you need to set the name of the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this coding for multiple file uploading....

```
    //For Multiple file uploading 
        if (isset($_FILES['photo']) != "") {
            $errors = array();
            foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $key = > $tmp_name) {
                $file_name = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
                $file_size = $_FILES['photo']['size'][$key];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $file_type = $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key];

                //change the image extension as png
                $fileExt = "png";
                $photorename[$key] = strtolower($property_code.
                    '_'.$key.
                    '.'.$fileExt);

                if ($file_size > 2097152) {
                    $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
                }

                //Path of Uploading file
                $target = "images_property";
                if (empty($errors) == true) {
                    if (is_dir($target) == false) {
                        mkdir("$target", 0700); // Create directory if it does not exist
                    }

                    if (file_exists("$target/".$photorename[$key])) {
                        unlink("$target/".$photorename[$key]);
                    }

                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$target/".$photorename[$key]);
                } else {
                    print_r($errors);
                }
            }

            if (empty($errors)) {
                echo "Success";
            }
        }
```